# Can UPDATE TIME of a Worker Photo in Workday be retrieved or used as filtered?

Tags: workday-api

I use Workday API methods **Get_Workers** and **Get_Worker_Photos** to download photo data for each worker (in order to populate photos in Azure by everyone's Workday photo).  But I must download over 1 GB of photo data every time I want to make sure I've got everyone's most recent photo.  I really want to retrieve or filter by *last updated times* for photos before I download them.

In each of these methods, there's a response filter **As_Of_Entry_DateTime** but this seems to filter by the date that a worker was added. Even within **Get_Worker_Photos**, it doesn't change response results after a user's photo is updated.

How can I download only photos from Workday that have been updated since a given datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Get_Workers you should be able to make the request with a transaction log scan for the *Photo Change - Photo Change Event* .  This will cause only those workers with a photo change to be included in the results.

Your webservice request would look something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <wd:Get_Workers_Request xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v35.2">
            <wd:Request_Criteria>
                <wd:Transaction_Log_Criteria_Data>
                    <wd:Transaction_Date_Range_Data>
                        <wd:Updated_From><!-- Launch datetime for last successful integrtion run --></wd:Updated_From>
                        <wd:Updated_Through><!--  Launch datetime for this integration  --></wd:Updated_Through>
                        <wd:Effective_From><!-- Date of last successful integration run --></wd:Effective_From>
                        <wd:Effective_Through><!-- Launch date of this integration --></wd:Effective_Through>
                    </wd:Transaction_Date_Range_Data>
                    <wd:Transaction_Type_References>
                        <wd:Transaction_Type_Reference>
                            <wd:ID wd:type="Business_Process_Type">Change Photo</wd:ID>
                        </wd:Transaction_Type_Reference>
                    </wd:Transaction_Type_References>
                </wd:Transaction_Log_Criteria_Data>
            </wd:Request_Criteria>
            <wd:Response_Filter>
                <wd:As_Of_Effective_Date><!-- Launch date of integration --></wd:As_Of_Effective_Date>
                <wd:As_Of_Entry_DateTime><!-- Launch datetime of integration --></wd:As_Of_Entry_DateTime>
                <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
                <wd:Count>999</wd:Count>
            </wd:Response_Filter>
            <wd:Response_Group>
                <wd:Include_Reference>true</wd:Include_Reference>
                <wd:Include_Photo>true</wd:Include_Photo>
               <wd:Exclude_Funds>true</wd:Exclude_Funds>
                <wd:Exclude_Fund_Hierarchies>true</wd:Exclude_Fund_Hierarchies>
                <wd:Exclude_Grants>true</wd:Exclude_Grants>
                <wd:Exclude_Grant_Hierarchies>true</wd:Exclude_Grant_Hierarchies>
                <wd:Exclude_Business_Units>true</wd:Exclude_Business_Units>
                <wd:Exclude_Business_Unit_Hierarchies>true</wd:Exclude_Business_Unit_Hierarchies>
                <wd:Exclude_Programs>true</wd:Exclude_Programs>
                <wd:Exclude_Program_Hierarchies>true</wd:Exclude_Program_Hierarchies>
                <wd:Exclude_Gifts>true</wd:Exclude_Gifts>
                <wd:Exclude_Gift_Hierarchies>true</wd:Exclude_Gift_Hierarchies>
            </wd:Response_Group>
        </wd:Get_Workers_Request>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Well this is an approach I was not aware of. Thank you, this looks very promising! I will test it and mark the question answered if I can get it to work.  Ideally I'd like to have it return all users but only include photo data when changed, which this doesn't seem to do, but this is better than no solution which is where I am now.

Comment: Yep, this is working for me, thank you for clarifying these "undocumented" details. How did you find this?  The API guide mentions Business_Process_Type (http://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v20/Get_Workers.html#Transaction_Log_TypeObjectType) but not "Change Photo" nor any other possible values that may be useful.

Comment: For Workday integrations it would be more normal to use the the Subscriber_Reference to instead pass in a reference to an integration system configured with a configured transaction log service.  To find the reference for the relevant BP I configured an integration system for this BP event then used Get_Integration_Systems webservice call in order to get the reference ID for it.

You hadn't said if you were making the webservice call from a Workday integration or from an external client so I gave you the approach that would work with either.

Comment: Using txn log in API calls is covered at https://community.workday.com/articles/1269.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to get access to that in the past since I support Workday customers. Trying again, hopefully I'll be able to get in this time so I can learn how to help people with Workday!